# Weird hover zone in css popup

Tags: css, popup, visibility

I've created a little popup menu for a page I'm working on, using just css. Basically, I've got this

```
.debug-menu {
    position: absolute; z-index:101;
    width: 50px; height: 20px; padding: 15px; top: 30px; right: 30px;
    background: #f00505; color: white;
}
.debug-menu:hover {
    width: 150px; height: 180px;
}
```

and stuff like this for the content:

```
.debug-menu .label {
    position: relative; padding-right: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.debug-menu:hover .label {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHJm6/2/). It works more or less as intended, expanding and showing its content when hovered. If you approach with the mouse from the left, the hover event happens correctly, right when you cross into the div. The weird (maybe I'm just not using css right, though) thing is, if you approach from BELOW, the :hover happens WAY too soon, i.e. when the mouse is below the edge of the div. Also, it flickers as the mouse is moved around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out, thanks to Stack Overflow's awesome "Similar Questions" feature, but I'm gonna post it anyway in case any other noob has the same problem.

USE DISPLAY INSTEAD OF VISIBILITY!!! (Here's the *working* [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHJm6/8/).)

The relevant line:

```
.debug-menu .label {
    position: relative; padding-right: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.debug-menu:hover .label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace following CSS instructions this way :

```
.debug-menu h3 {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display:none;
}

.debug-menu hr {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.debug-menu:hover h3 {
   display:block;
}
```

(h3 overflows outside its parent and cause :hover to be activated)